# Storing SQL Queries in a simple log file

Tags: java, sql, logging

We're trying to log some queries to see if a few performance issues of our app can be resolved. The problem is a basic one, how do we store the queries in a file that we can then be read in a fashion which allows us to parse each query without restricting new lines and special character and without wrapping the queries themselves in characters.

We cant restrict new lines, spaces etc. or wrap the query with some combination of characters (we actually tried the latter and although unlikely, one user ended up inserting that exact combination) because since its a db query, it really can contain anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use XML format, e.g.

```
<query timestamp="2014-03-23 11:12:00">
    SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
</query>
```

This can be built manually by doing simple string concatenation/manipulation, or using any XML API like JAXB, XStream, etc. If you construct the XML manually, don't forget to escape the XML character in the SQL (you can use StringEscapeUtils from Apache commons library to do this).

Alternatively, you can use Apache Log4J, defining the output as XML.
This is pretty decent tutorial about it: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/08/how-to-create-logs-in-xml-format-using-log4j/
Javadoc is here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/XMLLayout.html

Comment: Perhaps you can have a look at the Apache Log4J first since it already has built-in feature to log output in XML format. If it's not suitable to you, then you can build your own XML.

Comment: +1 - But you have a typo in your `</query>`